# Log file into Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a log file "sample.log" which looks like below:

```
41 Texas 2000
42 Louisiana4 3211
43 Texas 5000
22 Iowa 4998p
```

In the log file first column is id, second state name and third amount. If you see State name it has Louisiana4 and sales total it has 4998p. How can I cleanse it so I can insert it into Hive (using Python or other way?). Could you please show the steps?

I want to insert into Hive table tblSample:

Table schema is:

```
CREATE  TABLE tblSample(
id int, 
state string, 
sales int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/Staging'
;
```

To load data into Hive table I could do:

```
load data local inpath '/home/cloudera/sample.log' into table tblSample;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could load data as is into a hive table and then use UDFs to cleanse data and load into another table. This would be far more efficient than Python as it will be running as a mapr reduce.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather store the data as it is and do the cleansing while fetching the data. It would be much simpler. No external code required. For example :

```
hive> CREATE  TABLE tblSample( 
    > id string,
    > state string, 
    > sales string)
    > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    > STORED AS TEXTFILE
    > LOCATION '/user/cloudera/Staging';

hive> select regexp_replace(state, "[0-9]", ""), regexp_replace(sales, "[a-z]", "") from tblSample;
```

HTH

Comment: can I cleanse the data in log file itself either using some regex command?

Comment: Use a unix utility which suits you and then load the file into Hive table.